# Pasting columns in different sheet using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have the below code that will find and give the count if it matches the specific criteria:

```
Sub WBR()
Dim Count1Criteria As Variant
Dim Count3Criteria As Variant
Dim test As Variant
Dim wf As WorksheetFunction
Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction

Count1Criteria = Array(Array("AE4", "AE5", "Latency", "O:O", "Pass", "Fail"))
For Each test In Count1Criteria
With Worksheets(test(2))
    Range(test(0)) = wf.CountIfs(.Range(test(3)), test(4))
    Range(test(1)) = wf.CountIfs(.Range(test(3)), test(5))
    End With
    End Sub
```

I want to do the following:

- Once this criteria is met, instead of adding the count to the designated cell, the values in "M" col (named as "LATENCY") should be copied and pasted in "D" col in sheet.

Comment: Have you actually tried to accomplish your goal? If so, please show us what you have tried and where it's failing. SO is not a code-for-me site.

Comment: I have tried to add the search criteria, but i'm not sure on how to copy a specific col based on search criteria and paste in a different sheet.

Comment: where is your closing `Next` for your `For Each test In Count1Criteria` ? what exactly are you trying to achieve in the `With` section ??? which `Worksheet` is `Worksheets(test(2))` suppose to be ?  what are you trying to achieve in `Range(test(0)) = wf.CountIfs(.Range(test(3)), test(4))` ?

Comment: The above code is only to check for Keywords like "Pass", "Fail" in the given ranges and update the count in the cells. I can use this code to search for the keywords, but I'm stuck with the part after that. (i.e, once this condition is satisfied, the values in M column should be pasted into a different sheet) . I now figured out a below code to copy paste the column into a diff sheet, but dont know how to merge both the codes :

Comment: This is the code to copy paste the column into another sheet : `last_row = Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=XlSearchOrder.xlByRows,         SearchDirection:=XlSearchDirection.xlPrevious).Row
Range("M1:M" & last_row").select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
Range("D1").Select
Activesheet.Paste
Sheets("Sheet1").Activate`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does the job:

```
Sub sbMoveData()
Dim lRow As Integer, i As Integer, j As Integer
 'Find last roe in Sheet1

lRow = Sheet1.Cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row

j = 1
For i = 1 To lRow

If UCase(Sheet1.Range("A" & i)) = "COMPATIBLE" And UCase(Sheet1.Range("B" & i)) = "PASS" Then

Sheets("Sheet1").Range("M" & i).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & j)

j = j + 1

End If

Next
End Sub
```